# How to extract a single document out of a Lucene 4.0 index?

Tags: lucene, document, extract

This may be one of the simplest and dullest questions ever, but after indexing all the Documents in Lucene, how can I extract one Document only that has a specified id stored e.g. in a StringField? It should be an equivalent to e.g. an SQL-expression like

```
Select id, description 
from index
where id = '1'
```

Where the Document has two Fields, an ID and a description.
I already apologyze if this question had been asked too many times before etc. but after hours of searching the internet with probably wrong search terms, I decided to ask it here :)

Answer (score 0):

The Lucene demo shows how to use Lucene's standard QueryParser to search for documents: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/demo/overview-summary.html#overview_description

Answer (score 0):

Here is a an excellent tutorial on Lucene : [Lucene in 5 minutes](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html)

It will indeed take only 5 minutes, you will find the answer in sections Search, Display. You will find the query formation for your requirements in the "Query" section